# Is it possible using Pymssql to access SQL Server 2012 remotely, with domain (windows) user account

Tags: sql-server-2012, freetds, pymssql

I could not access SQL Server 2012 remotely using windows user account, even though its possible to access SQL Server after login to Windows OS with the same credentials.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Due to Security (OS Hardening) reason's SQL Server users are not supported

Trying to Access SQL 2012 remotely from CentOS

`telnet host 1433` #Works fine

TCP enabled in SQL Configuration manager.

`pymssql version - 2.1.0`

`pymssql.connect('192.168.1.7', 'mydomain\\dba', 'password', 'testdb')`

I'm getting below error

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> File "pymssql.pyx", line 599, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:9315) pymssql.OperationalError: (20002, 'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed\n')`

**FreeTDS configuration**

`tsql -C
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                            Version: freetds v0.91
             freetds.conf directory: /etc
     MS db-lib source compatibility: yes
        Sybase binary compatibility: yes
                      Thread safety: yes
                      iconv library: yes
                        TDS version: 4.2
                              iODBC: no
                           unixodbc: yes
              SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                           Kerberos: yes`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done during the connection:

```
pymssql.connect(
    server='192.168.1.7:1433',
    user='mydomain\\dba',
    password='password',
    database='testdb',
    tds_version='7.2'
)
```

Please note you'll have to be sure you can connect to the server SQL Server is running on from the machine you're running `pymssql` on. If things are locked down, you made need firewall modifications to be made. You can test to see if you can connect to your SQL Server server with telnet: `telnet your_host 1433` to see if it connects, or just hangs.

Comment: **pymssql.connect('192.168.1.7', 'domain\\dba', 'password', 'testdb')**

 I'm getting below error 
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> File "pymssql.pyx", line 599, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:9315) pymssql.OperationalError: (20002, 'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed\n')`

telnet worked fine...

Comment: Can you connect and get the `1>` prompt if you try: `TDSVER=7.2 tsql -H your_host -p 1433 -U YOUR_DOMAIN\\your_username -D your_database_name`?

Comment: I've also amended my answer, as I'm guessing your TDS version isn't being set correctly, and defaulting to version `4.2`.

Comment: I tried with TDSVER 7.2 AND 8 getting the same error....

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9a20bd47-a714-451a-a0f5-10d3262a8291/is-it-possible-using-pymssql-to-access-sql-server-2012-remotely-with-domain-windows-user-account?forum=sqlgetstarted